# Editing Zeus for Redis

Tags: redis, zeus

Is there a way to run `zeus start` and zeus will not only boot up rails, but redis as well?

I would do this in `custom_plan.rb` and on `CustomPlan#boot`, but I don't know how to start redis from within here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run system command in def boot of custom_pan.rb in the following manner :

```
exec(src/redis-server)
```

or incase you have installed redis as a service

```
exec(service redis start)
```